# How to sort hashmap by their values?Where value is object of type employee

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, comparator

I am having unsorted hashmap like

```
{ 
"001" : new Employee("vaibhav",22,"") ,"002" : new Employee("nik",19,""),"003" : new Employee("sunil",25,"")
}
```

I want to sort this hashmap according to Employee Age e.g. 22

O/P should be :

```
{ "002" : new Employee("nik",19,""),"001" : new Employee("vaibhav",22,""),"003" : new Employee("sunil",25,"")
}
```

Comment: This will help you. http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-2/

Comment: yes.. you need to use comparator interface... and override compare().

Comment: And you shouldn't confuse "Java" with "Javascript"...

Comment: thanks Prasad Kharkar.